# wildcard characters in struts-config, version 1.1

Tags: java, struts, wildcard

My application is using struts 1.1.
I'm trying to group URL forwards, using wildcards.

For example, if the action is like this:

 
action path="/edit/product" type="classname" 
  forward 
    name="success" 
    path=".myapp.main" 
action

Replacing the first line above with  
action path="/edit/*" type="classname" 
 doesn't work.  Any other step is required, to forward any URL beginning with /edit/ to myapp.main?

EDIT:
removed the brackets, as the code wasn't showing up.

Comment: Your code example is missing!

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge Struts does not support this type of wildcard configuration.

Answer (score 0):

laz, it does support.
I'm not sure if version 1.1 supports though.

http://www.oreillynet.com/onjava/blog/2004/12/struts_12_offers_cool_new_feat.html